# Bootstrap Image Div next to Filled with background text Div (responsive)

Tags: html, css

For now I have something like this:

[image]

And I want to make the div with text the same size as the div with image.

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

[image]

Code for now:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 ofimg">
            <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="img/oferta/x1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 oftext">
            <h3>Sesje ślubne</h3>
            <h4>Subheading</h4>
            <p>Przykładowy text.Przykładowy text.Przykładowy text.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="portfolio-item.html">Przeglądaj</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.oftext{
    background-color: #e2e0e0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
.ofimg {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you can give your `.row` a `display: flex;`

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2dv0hzsk/)